# Moving text in .Net without refreshing page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am still new to the coding field and am having a bit of trouble with a part, hoping someone can help me. I am working on a MVC page where i am trying to move text, the user inputs, around the page to a few pre-set spots and without having to refresh the page. Do i need a type of script for this? And if i do what would be best? Thanks for the help.

Comment: This can be done with client-side JavaScript.

Comment: Stop thinking about ASP.NET. Think how you would do it with just HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way.

```
Enter Text here... <input id="testText" type="text" onKeyUp="javascript:showText($(this), event);"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
See it here...  <span id="testTextSpan"></span>
```

Then, add this script...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var showText = function (el, e) {
    $('#testTextSpan').html(el.val());
};
<script>
```

See it here in this JSFiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/ZEcNp/

Be sure to include JQuery libraries in your project, or reference the CDN.

If you'd like me to include an example with raw javascript, with no JQuery, I can also provide that for you.

Comment: wow very helpful thanks, but now where it says " See it here" is there a way to move that to different spot with out changing the input? Im trying to  work on a chart where peoples names move based on organization.

Comment: Anything is possible, and yes, you can easily move it to a specific element.  You should take some time and learn some of the basics of javascript and dom manipulation, here...  http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: If I've been helpful, please do me a solid and vote me up.  :)

Comment: i would love to if i could. it says i need more rep? sorry im new to this site

Comment: Not a problem my friend.  I understand.  :)

Comment: hey Justin, could you actually provide for me the raw JS for me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend jQuery to do all that client-side.

You would just need an ID for each element you would use as the predefined spots, using either .appendTo, .insertAfter, .html, or something else depending on your exact needs.